# Binding jaydata entities to ko observable (also included ones)

Tags: knockout.js, odata, jaydata

I am using the jaydata ko modul to load an oData entity into a koObservable. Details are described [here](http://jaydata.org/blog/dynamic-queries-with-the-jaydata-knockout.js-module).

I'm using the following code:

```
self.productgroup = ko.observableArray();
context.ProductGroup.include('Product').toArray(self.productgroup);
```

This is working fine. Except that `self.productgroup()[0].Product()` are not observable. How can I archive that also the included entities are observable?

**Edit** (trying to clarify):

`self.productgroup()[0].Name` <- Is a KO-Observable

`self.productgroup()[0].Product().Price` <- Is **not** a KO-Observable

How can I get all extended entities as a KO-Observable?

Answer (score 0):

The productgroup is an array, you have to select an element in it:

```
self.productgroup()[i].Product()
```

where `i` is the index of the array